# Serial.available and raw_input in python, pyserial

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I am testing a simple arduino code with pyserial and I am unable to find the equivalent function to Serial.available in Arduino.

In the code I want to read the analog pin when I enter a key.

I used raw_input in python, but it does not act in a similar way to Serial.available in python.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', baudrate=9600, timeout =1)

while(1):

     userInput = raw_input('Enter txn')

     if userInput > 0:
          print(userInput)
          ser.write(userInput)
          print(ser.readline().decode('ascii'))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html), it says that **timeout=N** makes `read()` return after `N` seconds, therefore you could start by setting `timeout=None`. There is also `in_waiting` which returns the number of bytes in the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 

I am actually testing this simple code. 

User defines the number of blinks on the led. This works on arduino serial monitor. 

But when I use it in python it does not work. can anyone help?

Comment: did you set `timeout=None`?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Thank you for the quick reply. Yes I did. Now I am having trouble fixing this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113932/arduino-and-python-interface-pyserial-not-working?noredirect=1#comment71397081_42113932)

Comment: I answered your other question