# Arduino Sketch works with Serial Monitor but not with pyserial

Tags: python, interface, arduino, pyserial

I am testing this simple arduino code in python but it works in arduino serial not in python. 
User defines the number of blinks on the led. 
This works on arduino serial monitor. But when I use it in python it does not work. can anyone help?
Thank you

Arduino code:

```c
int ledPin = 13;   // select the pin for the LED
int val = 0;       // variable to store the data from the serial port

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);    // declare the LED's pin as output
  Serial.begin(9600);  

  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect (USB)
  }
  establishContact();
}

void establishContact(){
 while (Serial.available() <= 0){
    val = Serial.parseInt(); 
    Serial.flush();
//    Serial.println("Est");
  }
}

void loop () {
    if (val>0) {
    for(int i=0; i<val; i++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      delay(150);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(150);
    }
    val=0;
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421', baudrate=9600,timeout =None)

def blinkLED(x):
    ser.write(x)
    return;
```

Comment: how do you know it doesnt work? expected output and actual output? what have you tried?

Comment: Your `python` code does nothing, and *indeed nothing happens*: seems to be working fine. *Perhaps* you are missing a call to `blinkLED()` somewhere in your script..

Comment: In the python shell I call that function.. blinkLED('10'), make it to blink 10 times.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint when i call function blinkLED('10') in python shell the led does not blink 10times. 
but in the arduino IDE serial monitor it works perfect. when I enter 10 it blinks accordingly

Comment: Not on PC so can't format code. But is the blinkLED() function expecting integers not strings?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint no, blinkLED() function is expecting strings (that's why I input blinkLED('10')... on the arduino side I use Serial.parseInt().

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll assume that somewhere in your code you **do call**

```
blinkLED('10')
```

otherwise this entire discussion is pointless.

On this regard, I'd change your function `blinkLED(x)` as follows:

```
def blinkLED(x):
    ser.write(x)
    ser.flushOutput()
    return
```

---

Second, I am not fully convinced by this code:

```
1: void establishContact() {
2:    while (Serial.available() <= 0){
3:        val = Serial.parseInt(); 
4:        Serial.flush();
5:    }
6: }
```

First of all, I am not exactly sure what you think that `Serial.flush()` is supposed to do there, since according to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) it *"Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete"*, but you are not sending anything on `Serial` output.

Second, when you are at line `2:` at the first loop iteration, there are two possible cases:

- **A.** something is available on `Serial` input, therefore `Serial.available() > 0`, you don't enter the loop and you don't read `val`
- **B.** nothing is available on `Serial` input, therefore `Serial.available() == 0`, and you enter the loop. Now there are two sub-cases:

  - **B.1.** if nothing arrives on `Serial` input, you keep reading `0` forever, and remain stuck in that loop
  - **B.2.** if something arrives on `Serial` input, there are 3 sub-cases:

    - **B.2.I.** the input data arrives right after you execute `Serial.parseInt()`, so at the next loop iteration `Serial.available() <= 0` is false and you exit the loop without reading your `val` (that is, you end up in case **A.**)
    - **B.2.II.** the input data arrives right when you execute `Serial.parseInt()` and you successfully parse **all of the input bytes** into `val`. However, nothing remains within the `Serial` input, so the condition `Serial.available() <= 0` still holds and you remain stuck in the loop
    - **B.2.III.** the input data arrives right when you execute `Serial.parseInt()` and you successfully parse **some of the input bytes** into `val`. A few more bytes that **do not pertain an Int value** *(e.g. `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, space, alphabetic symbols, ...)* are ignored by `Serial.parseInt()` and remain in the `Serial` input buffer. Therefore at the next loop iteration `Serial.available() <= 0` is false and you exit the loop.

When you call `blinkLED('10')` you end up in one of the following cases: **A.**, **B.2.I.** or **B.2.II.**. This explains why you don't see any blinking: either you are still stuck in the loop, or you got past it without reading anything and you still have `val == 0`.

Case **B.2.III.** is the only situation in which you end up with a working **sketch**. This is what happens when you use the **Arduino** *serial monitor*, since the latter sends an additional `\n` *(or `\r\n`? I don't remember..)* by default when you press `enter` on your keyboard.

So I think this explains why your **sketch** works when you use the *serial monitor*, but not when you use the *python* code. A quick test would be to modify `blinkLED(x)` as follows:

```
def blinkLED(x):
    ser.write(x)
    ser.write('\n')
    ser.flushOutput()
    return
```

*Note: the fact that using the serial monitor works on a few tests, or that even `pyserial` might work with this fix, doesn't mean that your sketch is now correct and that it is always going to work. In fact, the code might still fail, e.g. if `Serial.available > 0` too soon then you still don't enter the loop body and parse `val`.*

---

@ArnoBozo proposed changing `establishContact()` as follows:

```
1: void establishContact() {
2:    while (Serial.available() > 0){
3:        val = Serial.parseInt(); 
4:        Serial.flush();
5:    }
6: }
```

I think that this design is *flawed* as well, because again you have *no guarantee* that by the time you check `Serial.available() > 0` the `python` counterpart has already sent the data *(or that it was received)*. If this is not the case, the *loop body* is simply not executed and you never parse `val`. Sure, you can try playing with `delay()`, but that makes the entire *sketch* quite fragile.

---

A final observation: if you look at the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/parseInt) of `Serial.parseInt()`, you find that:

> - Parsing stops when no characters have been read for a configurable time-out value, or a non-digit is read;
> - If no valid digits were read when the time-out (see Serial.setTimeout()) occurs, 0 is returned;

If you check the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout) of `Serial.setTimeout()` you find out that the `timeout` *"defaults to 1000 milliseconds"*. Again, at the cost of repeating myself and appearing pedantic, one should not rely on *timeouts* and *delays* in a communication protocol unless strictly necessary (e.g. to *heuristically* decide that it is time to *free resources* allocated to communicate with an external entity that is no longer participating to the communication).

Thus, my advice is to either **scratch** `Serial.parseInt()` and write your own parser, or use it in a more robust way wrt. the goal you have in mind:

```
Serial.setTimeout(0);            // disables timeout
while (val == 0) {               // discard any 'garbage' input
    val = Serial.parseInt();     // keeps trying to read an Int
}
```

This approach is rather *brutal* *(but YOLO)*: **Arduino** won't stop trying to parse an `int` different from `0` until when it gets one. Again, you should send an invalid digit after your number *(e.g. `\n`)* because otherwise `Serial.parseInt()` won't return since `timeout` is now equal to `0`.

*(note that I didn't test this code, it might as well not work if I misinterpreted some parts of the library documentation.)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you python script calls `blinkLED()` somewhere  and the message is received in `establishContact()` on your arduino.

But you should have written `Serial.available() > 0` (how many bytes are waiting to be read in incoming buffer).

You can erase following lines:

```
while (!Serial) { }  // DOES NOT wait for serial port to connect (USB)
```

Indeed Serial object is instanciated at compile time and immediately returns (except with one board: Leonardo ?).

`Serial.flush()` empty outgoing buffer you are not using here; it does nothing on incoming buffer.

In your python script when you open serial port to arduino, this will surely reset arduino board; that will last less than 2s. So:

- python can wait that arduino sends you a hello messsage.
- or python can wait for 2s, before sending `blinkLED()` message.

If you open your arduino IDE serial monitor, it resets your arduino board, but you can not type in and send message before the board is ready, so you dont see the problem.

What happens with that bugged code:

```
while (Serial.available() <= 0){
   val = Serial.parseInt();  }
```

It enters the `while` loop if there is no data waiting on serial. Then the `Serial.parseInt()` will be waiting a timeout of 1s for incoming data. If nothing comes, it will return 0.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added a wait time (time.sleep(2)) before the function blinkLED() call.
When I call the function blinkLED('10') the expected output is to blink the led 10 times. but nothing happens. 
I pass the value '10' as a string but in the arduino side it converts it to integer. 
But in arduino IDE serial monitor it works perfect.

Comment: As usual we will understand with tracing. You can initialize with `val=2` so that you will see LED blinking when arduino enters main loop; even if it failed reading serial. You can add `val=4;` inside `establishContact()`, before `val = Serial.parseInt();` ; and in python you send `blinkLED('10')`. This way you will know how the code works.